# Initializing Nested strongly typed objects in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#-4.0, properties, linq-to-entities, complextype

Consider this Example

```
    public class FooWrapper
{
    public FooWrapper() { }

    public Foo FooObject { get; set; }
    public Bar BarObject { get; set; }
}


public IEnumerable<FooWrapper> ListFoosWithBars(int userID)
{
    IEnumerable<Bar> tempBar = ListBarsByUserID(userID);

    IEnumerable<FooWrapper> results = (
        from f in _entities.FooSet
        join b in tempBar on f.ID equals b.foos.ID
        select new FooWrapper 
        {
            FooObject = f,
            BarObject = b
        });

    return results;
}
```

what if my Foo type class has Properties like

```
public class Foo(){
FProperty1{get; set;}
FPorperty2{get; set;}
}

public class Bar(){
BProperty1{get; set;}
BProperty2{get; set;}
}
```

and now i want to initialize my object in query like this

```
 select new FooWrapper 
        {
            FooObject.FProperty1 = f,
            BarObject.BProperty2 = b
        });
```

can I do this?
How will this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is:

```
select new FooWrapper 
    {
        FooObject = new Foo { FProperty1 = f },
        BarObject = new Bar { BProperty2 = b }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much i was been looking for this from long time.